# Connect BURP suite to the Mobile application

Tags: android, testing, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing a hybrid android mobile application using jquery mobile and running my application in a phone gap. I want to test this application using BURP suite for security issues. I am new to BURP Suite. How do I connect my application to the BURP Suite? In my emulator, I have tried to change the proxy settings

host:http://127.0.0.1 or 127.0.0.1 
port:8080

but nothing is working. Can someone guide me exactly how can i test my application using BURP suite?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your application in android emulator, and set the proxy point to burp proxy

./emulator -avd vdtest -http-proxy 127.0.0.1:8080

Answer (score 0):

For web app testing Phone apps from Burp try setting up a Linux router in your network that is passing your phones wireless traffic. Then redirect the HTTP / SSL to Burp using iptables.

[Proxy phone to Burp Suite](https://hackertarget.com/proxy-phone-burp/)